# Appfabric and WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, appfabric

I need to know whether it is rule of thumb to use WCF webservice inorder to use appfabric. Actually we have lots of files to be download from a IIS server to iphone. The thing is like we all have WCF services and we are actually avoiding MTOM stuff as it is little complicated to process the filedownload on iphone. So we thought of using a typical file download asp.net page to get the file.

Appfabric is actually used to cache all files to make download easy.

My question is my decision of using a asp.net page to download a file can affect the integration of the app fabric ?

Since i am fully not aware of .net, pardon me if it is a very basic question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement to use web services to access an AppFabric cache. I don't think AppFabric's established enough yet for best practices/rules of thumb to have been deduced.

If it's easier/makes more sense to you to use an ASP.NET page for downloading your files to the iPhone browser, then go for that.